# Hide component when certain component shown (with react router)

Tags: react-router

I have render function below.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={TestApp}/>
                        <Route exact path="/chat" component={ChahtView1}/>
                        <Route exact path="/chat/invite" component={ChatView2}/>
                        <Route exact path="/chat/chatting" component={ChatView3}/>
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
 }
```

In this condition, every page shows `Header` component. What I want to do is to hide `Header` when `NotFound` component appears.

How can I do this? Help me please!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'location' object provided by 'withRouter' from react-router-dom to conditionally show or hide components like:

```
const Main = withRouter(({location}) => (
<div>
 {location.pathname !== "/" && <Header/>}
   <Switch location={location}>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="/first-page" component={First}/>
    <Route path="/second-page" component={Second}/>
    <Footer />
   </Switch>
<div>
)
```

More info on 'location' here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. 
The only way I found is changing component's state from child component and displaying `<Header />` upon its state.

So, first I've added `showHeader` state and function which will false this state, pass this func to `<NotFound />`:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showHeader: true
    }
  }

  hideNavigation = () => {
    this.setState({
      showHeader: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          {this.state.showHeader && <Header/>}

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={TestApp}/>

            <Route render={ (props) => (
                <NotFound
                    hideNavigation={this.hideNavigation}
                    {...props}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

And then calling `hideNavigation()` from `<NotFound />` component:

```
class NotFound extends Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.hideNavigation()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>Ooops!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since React Router 5.1 there is the hook useLocation which lets you easily access the current location.

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function HeaderView() {
  let location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.pathname);
  return <span>Path : {location.pathname}</span>
}
```